# iframe not displaying youtube

Tags: html5-video, embed, youtube-iframe-api

I've searched for several days with the problem embedding a video via 
and can't find the proper solution to this prob.

I'm editing a purchased web html5 template on localhost using FF on Linux.

The HTML

```
 <!-- blog side -->
<section class="blog-side sp-seven blog-style-one standard-post video-post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-side">
                <div class="blog-details-content">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="videowrapper">
                        <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/NNcvbxIODsY?start=15" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The CSS

```
  .blog-side {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;

} 
.videowrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0px;
}

.videowrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The video does not display, but gets this error code - *File Not Found*:

[image: How is this possible]

The embed code that I get from YT is long and has many attributes I'm not interested in, and have deleted some of them with the same results.

Could this be a .js problem?

Answer (score 0):

How is your html file named? I think you're not targeting correctly your html file *(which contains the iframe and the rest of the code)*.

---

I'm saying this because your screenshot shows that **file named `<iframe width=...` does NOT exist**.

Your path should be like:

```
/home/esmeralda/Desktop/Belfast/myFile.html
```

Here, **myFile.html** is the file *(with .html extension)* which has your source code "iframe, css styles, etcetera".

Comment: I understand your example, however, doesn't the <iframe> load the file from the external website (in this case, YouTube?)

Comment: @jim can you tell me the name of the HTML file that contains your iframe?